# I want to disable E-Mail verifcation / activation when a user signs up for my Wordpress site

Tags: login, user-registration, wp-login-form

when a new user registers an activation link is sent to his e-mail account. I want the user to enter his username, email address and password and straight register and be logged in without confirmation (confirmation does not prevent spam bots from signing up for the site, I don't care about it really!)

is there a way to do it?

Comment: Sure, if that really is what you want: **1.** Make your own registration form inside modal or new page with every field you need **2.** Make your own input validation,  data checking and saving via ajax or not **3.** Disable registration email sending **4.** Disable _activation key_ feature so that user can login right away without confirmation emails etc. There should be plenty of tutorials about each of these steps online. This is way too broad question for this site because it covers bunch of different questions / topics.

Comment: so basically you are saying it is very difficult to do and there is no plugin or complete tutorial. Is there a way I can easily improve, the to be honest, pretty bad registration flow? after the e-mail activation link and setting the password, the user gets redirected to the login page, then has to manually enter his username and password again, and then finally gets redirected to the frontpage of wordpress, not the page he pressed register on.

Comment: specifically I cannot find something for `3. Disable registration email sending` (there is a lot about the notification sent to the web master, but that' is not what this is about really) `4. Disable activation key feature`

Comment: Maybe this link in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification) and this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/) will guide you without the need for 3rd party plugins and you create your own function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use plugins for do that
also have a lot of plugins for this purpose below some of them may be useful for you

[Remove Email Verification Plugin](http://pastebin.com/se5NBVcH)

[BP Disable Activation Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-disable-activation/)

[REMOVE EMAIL VERIFICATION](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/remove-email-verification-from-signup/)

Comment: WPSE is for developing and not, as you did, for listing plugins. If you have no code to help please just skip questions and do not answer the way you did here.