# What speaks against using a custom login.php / register.php to wordpress?

Tags: login, user-registration

[I had a problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213457/i-want-to-disable-e-mail-verifcation-activation-when-a-user-signs-up-for-my-wo), then I saw that I can just use

`wp_insert_user( $userdata );`

if it passes i can just directly `wp_signon` and redirect.

Basically:

```
$user_login = "test32xac";
$password = "test123";
$user_email = "j151xbcaxx295@trbvm.com";
//register_new_user($user_login, $user_email);
// Setup the minimum required user information for this example
$userdata = array( 'user_email' => $user_email,
  'user_pass' => $password,
  'user_login' => $user_login,
  'nickname' => "dirk",
  'first_name' => "dieter",
  'display_name' => "dieter baumann",
  'rich_editing' => true,
  'role' => 'contributor',
);
$new_user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ); // A new user has been created
$res = wp_signon(array("user_login" => $user_login, "user_password" => $password));
wp_redirect(get_permalink(10));
```

Is there something that would speak against using this method?

Answer (score 2):

To register some new user? Go ahead. As a general purpose registration system? No. Don't do that. You lose a lot of functionality, like the ability to reset passwords. Take a look at the volume of code in [`wp-login.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-login.php). You are losing virtually all of that and replacing it with about a dozen lines.

Other than the registration and password reset/retrieval handling starting about [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-login.php#L424) you are losing around 30 hooks (I'm not swearing to an accurate count) which means that numerous plugins will not function correctly.